# Ctrl+P in Rgui.exe on Windows does not move to the previous history in console, but open up a printing window, instead

Tags: r, windows, shortcut, readline

Reproducible on R 3.3.1 (64bit) on Windows 7, 8.1, and 10 (64bit)

1. Start Rgui.exe (R Console)
2. Type Ctrl + P, then it will launch a printing window instead of moving to one previous history in a R console, which is the behavior I'd expect.

Actually, what makes me feel worse is all the other major shortcuts derived from readline keybindings such as Ctrl+n, Ctrl+a, Ctrl+e, Ctrl+f, Ctrl+b, and even Ctrl+k do well, however, Ctrl+P is the only keybinding with Rgui.exe on Windows, which won't work as expected.

I'd like to know if there is any way or workaround, if available, to let Ctrl+P work as usual so that I would not have to reach out for arrow keys to move a line backward in a R console every time I need to do so, which is really cumbersome, and unproductive.

I appreciate any information, or suggestion.

regards.

Masaru

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 64 bit and R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks, @Marichyasana, for sharing the information. 
Oh, yes, you are right!  I downloaded and installed R 3.1.2 "Pumkin Helmet" x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) on my Windows 10, it turned out Ctrl+P let you go to the previous line in R Console on this version. While I'm going to look into the change history of the software, does any one have idea, just in case, in which version of R the behavior changed, and why ?

Comment: Following up on my own, I found the trace here; [R news, Changes in R3.2.3](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html) 
(Windows only) Shortcuts for printing and saving have been added to menus in Rgui.exe. (Request of [PR#16572](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16572).)

Comment: It looks like the behavior change was made to the software to meet the request from some federal department, based on Review of R's accessibility strengths/weaknesses 1.3 conducted on Oct. 2015. 
I think it's basically a good thing to enhance features of software in a new version to meet more customers needs, but I do not think it is right to break backward compatibility without providing a way to let it behave as it used to do.